# Change the default file manager applications use to open files (ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: 16.04, filemanager, krusader

I am currently using ubuntu 16.04. When I am using applications, such as Kile, to open documents I have to use ubuntu's default file manager. Right now I have Krusader installed(my choice of file manager).

How can I make it so that all applications (including Kile) use Krusader to open files?

Answer (score 2):

Well Open terminal and install exo-utils

```
sudo apt-get install exo-utils
```

Now run the following command in terminal

```
exo-preferred-applications
```

Under Utilies Tab you will have File Manager to choose.

If you are using Xubuntu distros then go to
**Settings Manager > Preferred Applications > Utilities** , there you have the dropdown option to select the File Managers you already installed.

---

if above things fails then try running following command in a new terminal.

```
xdg-mime default Krusader.desktop inode/directory application/x-gnome-saved-search
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. However, I tried this solution and it did not work. When I click on the tabs in the Preferred Application window I get this error "(exo-helper-1:20840): Gdk-CRITICAL **: IA__gdk_window_get_window_type: assertion 'GDK_IS_WINDOW (window)' failed" . Also tried the las line and nothing happen.