# VS Code opens up whenever I try to open some file

Tags: files, 22.04, default-programs

I recently installed vs code onto my ubuntu 22.04 system, and it has started opening directories in vs code instead of nemo (file manager).
Any way to fix this?
Thanks for any help
Wallaby

Comment: Can you check if this works? https://askubuntu.com/a/816818/124466 You can use this to change your file manager.

Comment: I installed exo-utils but upon running the exo-preferred-applications command the terminal just tells me that such a command doesn't exist. I also do not have a desktop icon for my files so xdg-mime doesn't work.

Comment: Nevermind, It seems I did something wrong before, using xdg mime solved my problems, thanks for the help :)